# how to get max high of the given days excluding weekly off days

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

Can any one help how to get maximum high of given days excluding weekly off days (sat/sunday) from google finance.

I am using formula like: =query(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:"&Y3,"high",(TODAY()-55),TODAY()),"Select Max(Col2) label Max(Col2)''")

However, it doesn't exclude weekly off days. I have tried to use WORKDAY / workday.intl functions but unable to fetch the correct day. Pls help me.

Comment: What about holidays? What exactly are you trying to receive from that GoogleFinance function?

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question to "How to get the high of a given number of valid trading days with the GoogleFinance function"

Answer (score 0):

I am grabbing the last 365 valid trading days as reported by GoogleFinance then with array_constrain we are basically saying grab the last 55 trading days to get the highest.

```
=query(array_constrain(GOOGLEFINANCE("F","high",(TODAY()-365),TODAY()),55,2),"Select Max(Col2) label Max(Col2)''")
```

You do not have to use Query so you can do something like this:

```
=max(index(array_constrain(GOOGLEFINANCE("F","high",(TODAY()-365),TODAY()),55,2),,2))
```